# All payment options disappear when processing Recurring Profiles

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal

I'm having issues with the processing Recurring Profiles in Mangeto.

I have Paypal Payments Standard and Authorize.net as payment methods.

Authorize.net has an add on service called "Automated Recurring Billing" which is a tool for submitting and managing recurring, or subscription-based, transactions. Which I also have enabled on Authorize.net end.

Whenever I try and checkout with a product with a Recurring Profile all payment methods disappear. This happens on the frontend and the backend.

Does anyone know why this is or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure on this and never used Recurring Payment, but I would say every payment method is checked for:

```
\Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::canManageRecurringProfiles

/**
 * Whether can manage recurring profiles
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function canManageRecurringProfiles()
{
    return $this->_canManageRecurringProfiles && ($this instanceof Mage_Payment_Model_Recurring_Profile_MethodInterface);
}
```

if this is true, then it is shown, if not - then not ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the response. So are you just suggest I look for this or look and if I don't see it add it. @FabianBlechschmidt

Comment: No, you can't just change this. Your payment provider needs to support this and at least in germany there are not many which do this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use Paypal Payments Standard or Authorize.net for the recurring profiles in Magento, currently Magento supports purchasing items with recurring profiles only for the PayPal payment system and only through the Express Checkout method.

Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles/

Comment: I keep saying this and people continue to not listen to me :)

Comment: Actually any other payment method from 3rd party extension who declares `$_canCreateBillingAgreement = true` will be show in the list too.

Comment: Well is there any point then for me to be paying the extra $10 a month to Authorize.net for Automated Recurring Billing? I think I was under the impression it would integrate into my system like the normal payment authorize.net processing would @vladimirKerkhoff

Comment: You can try the aheadWorks solution for recurring billing, they support Authorize.net. Never worked with the extension but maybe it works in your case, see: http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/subscriptions-and-recurring-payments.html.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement Mage_Payment_Model_Recurring_Profile_MethodInterface and all its methods(even stubs work) in your payment method class and it should appear in the payment methods for nominal items. It works.

Comment: Hi @nitin Pant thanks for responding. Are you speaking of an extension? Or is this something I just need to enable in Magento?

Comment: You'll need to write code for this. Its easy. PM/email me for details